# formatting web gallery

Tags: html, css, gallery

i am using the following code to create a small web gallery. right now the thumbnails are placed vertically, and id like them to run horizontally below the main image. does anyone have any suggestions for how to do so?

```html
<div id="content">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myshowImages(id) {

             /**$(".bigPic").hide();
                $("#pic-"+id).show();*/
                $('.bigPic').css({'display':'none'});
                $("#pic-"+id).fadeIn('slow'); 

        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.email-sign-up').css({'marginBottom':'0px'});        
        })
    </script>

    <div class="product">
        <div class="galerie">
            <div class="bigPics">
                <a href="insert" target="_blank">
                    <img src="insert" title="" alt="" id="pic-0" width="450" height="450" class="bigPic" name="bigPic"  />
                </a>
                <a href="insert" target="_blank">
                    <img src="insert" title="" alt="" id="pic-1" width="450" height="450" class="bigPic" name="bigPic" style="display:none;" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div class="mini-thumb">
                    <a href="javascript:myshowImages(0)" >
                        <img src="insert" title="" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="mini-thumb">
                    <a href="javascript:myshowImages(1)" >
                         <img src="insert" title="" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` elements wrapping your thumbs have a default CSS style of `display: block`, which causes an element to take up 100% of the horizontal space available to it. You could change this with the following rule:

```css
.mini-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

- [`display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display)
- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/gwwh6/)

As a side note, well-indented markup can help you identify problems such as missing closing `</div>` tags, which may contribute to formatting issues.

Comment: thank you! i added what you suggested to my CSS and it didn't change. perhaps its because i am using blogger or is there something else i could try?

Comment: @user1253957 the style may be overriden, try making it `display: inline-block !important;`

Comment: @user1253957 not sure what to tell you, there could be other factors at play but I don't see them based on your code example. Added a demo to the answer to illustrate my point.

Comment: hmm, must be something strange with blogger. i will keep trying, thank you!